# getting error when trying to read from DataGridView with event handler winform

Tags: winforms, exception, datagridview, eventhandler

I have a winform that has a gridview that I am applying data to via a Dataset.  When the data binds, it calls the SelectionChanged event handler.  I researched that and found a way around it by adding an if clause to see if the DGV has focus (all other resolutions did not work that I found).  That part is working as planned.  When I step through the program, the event handler tries to go through the code 3 times when it binds the data.  The if clause stops it from reaching the code.  My issue is after the data binds and I then choose a row in the DGV, the event handler then throws "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll".  When stepping through the code, the DGV is returning the proper row index to my 'int row' variable, but the code I use to get the row/cell info throws the error before it applies it to the 'loadtableID' variable.  I need help.  You can ignore the second DGV in the top.  It takes the selected row's info and gets another DB table info.  Also, if it helps, I did not apply a datasource to the program or create datasets for each individual dataset that is returned, I am using the system's generic Dataset when returning data.

```
     private void gvMainSelectResults_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (gvMainSelectResults.Focused)
        {
            gvMainArchiveResults.DataSource = null;  //second DGV that is populated later and everytime is cleared with a new selection

            loadTableID = 0;
            orgID = 0;
            dbFileName = "";
            sourceType = "";

            int row = gvMainSelectResults.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
            loadTableID = Convert.ToInt32(gvMainSelectResults.SelectedRows[row].Cells["LoadTableID"].Value);  //this is where I get the error, even if the "int row" has the correct index number
            orgID = Convert.ToInt32(gvMainSelectResults.SelectedRows[row].Cells["OrganizationID"].Value);
            dbFileName = Convert.ToString(gvMainSelectResults.SelectedRows[row].Cells["FileName"].Value);
            sourceType = Convert.ToString(gvMainSelectResults.SelectedRows[row].Cells["SourceType"].Value);

            more code here...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the RowIndex value to get your text from the SelectedRows collection.
But this collection contains only

> Gets the collection of rows selected by the user.

This means that the collection contains only a subset of the rows present in your grid. When RowIndex is 2 and you have just one row in the SelectedRows collection you get the OutOfRange exception.

With the RowIndex value you should refer to the Rows collection instead

```
loadTableID = Convert.ToInt32(gvMainSelectResults.Rows[row].Cells["LoadTableID"].Value);
orgID = Convert.ToInt32(gvMainSelectResults.Rows[row].Cells["OrganizationID"].Value);
dbFileName = Convert.ToString(gvMainSelectResults.Rows[row].Cells["FileName"].Value);
sourceType = Convert.ToString(gvMainSelectResults.Rows[row].Cells["SourceType"].Value);
```

Comment: That DGV you are referring to is not the same one, it is a different one.  I have 2 (gvMainSelectResults, which is the one that is populated, and gvMainArchiveResults, which uses the info from the first one to populate the second, so everytime they chose a new row, the 2nd DGV clears itself and will apply the new dataset).  That is why the gvMainArchiveResults was placed at the top on the code.

Comment: I see, but I think I have found the problem now. updating the answer

Comment: Steve, do you happen to know the answer of why when the datasource is applied to the 1st gridview, the event handler is called and it runs through it 3 times in a row?  I would like the first line item in the 1st dataset to populate the 2nd datasource with the Archive data and have my variables keep the info.  Because if only one item is returned, I don't want to have the user to have to physically choose the one item.

Comment: No idea, something else happens caused by the DataSource settings. Do you have other event handlers? In the  _more code here..._ part do you have some code that could change the current selected row? It is very difficult to say without your whole code and data. You could try commenting out part of code and checking if something changes in your event handler, or just remove the setting of the event handler from the designer set it in code AFTER setting the DataSource then select from code the first row

Comment: no, it happens even if I have no code in the event handler.  It still runs through the brackets 3 times.  I have never had this happen when I have individual datasets created for each table that I access in the DB.  Its just this time I would have too many to create, so I used the included Dataset on winforms.  I could remove the if clause and just have it run through the code 3 times now that we have fixed my indexing error...

Comment: no errors, but it does run through the event handler 3 times in a row once the dataset is bound to the datasource.